# Open ground on new receptacle

Tags: receptacle

Receptacle for TV shorted out along with power in bathroom and circuit breaker. Replaced receptacle with same wire set up, reset circuit breaker. Receptacle comes up open neutral and bathroom receptacle reads hot & ground reverse and light switch in bathroom not working.

Comment: It sounds like you got a couple of wires crossed. If the old receptacle had wires on both sides then there are a few different possibilities. If you post pictures of the receptacle with its wires attached that may help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you post photos of the situation in the receptacle box?